# Rx Java2 handle asynchronous timeout exception

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm working on some concurrent io operation. The code below is a test code for my architecture. I want to give timeout to async io operations but the flow stucks after some steps. When i discard the timeout func code works well.

What i'm missing ? Where is the problem ?

```
    Scheduler mainObserveOn = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    Scheduler mainSubscribeOn = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    Scheduler flatmapObserveOn = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));
    Scheduler flatmapSubscribeOn = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));

    AtomicLong a = new AtomicLong();
    Flowable.create(emitter -> {

        while(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                emitter.onNext(a.incrementAndGet());
                System.out.println("Emit : "+a.get()+" | Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .observeOn(mainObserveOn)
    .flatMap(
            o -> Flowable.just(o)
                    .observeOn(flatmapObserveOn)
                    .doOnNext(o1 -> {
                        System.out.println(o1+" | Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

                        if( (long)o1 % 10 == 0 )
                        {
                            System.out.println("SLEEP");
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                    })
                    .doOnError(throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace())
                    .onExceptionResumeNext(s -> {})
                    .timeout(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(flatmapSubscribeOn)
    )
    .subscribeOn(mainSubscribeOn)
    //.blockingSubscribe(System.out::println, System.err::println);
    .subscribe(System.out::println, System.err::println);


    Thread.sleep(1000000000000000000L);
```

By the way i want to skip the error operations so using empty onExceptionResumeNext. Is there better way for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout code inside `doOnNext()` will cause the observer chain to sleep for 10 seconds every 10 emissions. Later, you have a `timeout()` for 2 seconds; this will trigger on the tenth emission, causing `onError()` to be emitted. You have no error handling code after this, so it will likely cause the entire observer chain to quit.

The result will be 101 log lines for the initial emissions, followed by 10 log lines for the first 10 emissions followed by an error message, likely `Timeout`.

It isn't clear what you want to happen, but this is what you get.

Comment: Yes thats all true but the case is this code is not stopping when an error occurs but after some time it stops for unknown reason. I m wondering this reason not the work flow. Did you run this code ?

Comment: It won't necessarily all stop immediately because you have multiple threads with multiple `sleep()` actions going. In any case, when you mix RxJava scheduling and `sleep()`, you are crossing lines. Remember: `sleep()` is not **composable**; RxJava tries to compose elements into observer chains.

Comment: You say when i use timout current thread is changing am i true?

Comment: The `timeout()` operator runs by default on the `Schedulers.computation()` scheduler. It will emit the exception on that scheduler.